# android How to set WindowManger align to Center inital then can drag to anywhere on screen

Tags: android

I want to create a window by WindowManger addView

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    // set align style, usal use Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT
    mLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER ;
    //inital place 

    mLayout.x = 0;
    mLayout.y = 0;
```

but onTouch method can not drag normal

```
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    mTouchStartX = event.getX();
                    mTouchStartY = event.getY();

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    mLayout.x = (int) (x - mTouchStartX );
                    mLayout.y = (int) (y - mTouchStartY );

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    // update
                    mLayout.x = (int) (x - mTouchStartX );
                    mLayout.y = (int) (y - mTouchStartY );

                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(v, mLayout);

                    // last place

                    mTouchStartX = mTouchStartY = 0;
                    break;
                default:
```

when i drag view element appear buttom, why ???

Comment: If it solves the problem then you can post your comment as an answer (and accept it). It would be easier for other users to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the reason! when set the

```
mLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER ;
```

the current center of screen X and Y is base of drag and coordinate is zero, so when I drag, my view element appear buttom!

```
float offsetX = (SystemVal.sysWidth - ScreenUtil.dip2px(View's width))/2;
float offsetY = (SystemVal.sysHeight - ScreenUtil.dip2px(View's height))/2;
mLayout.x = (int) (x - mTouchStartX - offsetX );
mLayout.y = (int) (y - mTouchStartY - offsetY );
```

work fine